# why there is no install.sh or install-templates.sh file in Cocos2d 3.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6

I've googled to find solution for installing Cocos2d in Xcode 6. There are many tutorials about installing Cocos2d, in every tutorial they explained with  install.sh or install-templates.sh. I've downloaded the Cocos2d couple of times but I didn't find  install.sh or install-templates.sh. In terminal its showing the error install.sh or install-templates.sh command not found. Can anyone tell me the way of installation here.

Comment: are you find the solution. even i didn't find the install.sh file. if you got the solution update here for others.

Answer (score 1):

The install.sh file is included in the cocos2D v3.4 directory.

For installation you can perform the following steps:
1. Open terminal from the cocos2D v3.4 folder and drag the install.sh file.
2. Type ./install.sh -d  and then ./install.sh -i
3. Done!

Screenshots:
[Location of install.sh file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlF4L.png)

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMpow.png)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install cocos2d with version 3.x is to install SpriteBuilder (available free from the Mac AppStpre). SpriteBuilder will install cocos2d for use with itself, or as a standalone third party library, with XCode.

Comment: i've just installed spritebuilder, but how to link it to the xcode for cocos 2d.

Comment: if you start XCode, and create new project, you should see iOS category for cocos v3.x templates

Comment: hmmm ... does for me. Dont know what to say. Maybe try to create a 'SpriteBuilder' project, inside there should be the xcodeproj file for the SpriteBuilder ... and start from there. I feel the SB move was a real bad idea myself, but the cocos2d v3 branch is really good, so i suffer through SB (s)crap.

Comment: i created a helloWorld project then from the sandbox i got helloWorld.xcodeproj. I run it with xcode in simulator its showing default logo and background. but still i didn't got at the  iOS category. i think its only to check sprite sheets

Answer (score 0):

1. Please download lastest version from : https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc
2. Unzip and using terminal to install Cocos2D.
3. Drag and drop file install.sh or template-install.sh to terminal.
4. Please do the same guide: ./install.sh -i   to install Cocos2D
                            ./install.sh -u   to update Cocos2D
                            ./install.sh -d   to delete Cocos2D
   I hope you can make some nice game.
   Thank you.

Comment: did u read my question there is no install.sh file in extracted file